# How update the password in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
 app.get('/changePass', function(req, res) {
password = req.body.password;
password1 = req.body.password1;
xyz = req.body.xyz;

User.find({ email: xyz, password: password }, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    if (data.length === 0) {
        return res.json({ success: false, data: 'please enter valid 
   Old password' })
    } else {

        // User.update({ password: password }, {
        //     $set: {
        //         password: password1
        //     }
        // });
         var usr = new User();
        usr.update({ "password":password }, password1, { upsert:true 
   });
        //usr.password = password;
        usr.save(function(err, data) {
            if (err)
                throw err;
            return res.json({ success: true, data: 'password changed 
 successfully' });
        })
    }
   })
```

how i update password in mongodb i am matching password to password and updating password to password1.this is giving me alert with please enter valid old password.
xyz is cookie that contains email.

Comment: The commented code actually uses the correct approach (except you forgot the callback), and you also need not do the `.findOne()` when using that since `User.update()` take the first argument as the "query" to match the document on. The `usr.update()` is wrong because as an "instance" there is no "query" part. And you should still use `$set` as in `usr.update({ "$set": { "password": password1 },function(err) { ..`. But again, you need not do that where the other form is better. You also really do not want to send plain text passwords in the clear, or store them that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use findOne on model to return userObject.
Then you can update the object that was found like regular javascript object and save it with .save function.

```
User.findOne({email: xyz, password: req.body.password1}, function(err, user){
 if(err)return handleErr(err);
 user.password = req.body.password2;
 user.save(function(err){
    if(err)return handleErr(err);
    //user has been updated
  });
});
```